# Why implement cucumber stepdef with lambda expression is a good practice?

Tags: java, lambda, cucumber

As we know, with the new Cucumber-Java8 API, we can write our step definitions with lambda expressions. 
Example code from github-cucumber:

```
package foo;

import cucumber.api.java8.En;

public class TestLambdaStepdefs implements En {

    //Lambda-steps inside Constructors
    public TestLambdaStepdefs() {
        Given("I have (\\d+) cukes in my belly", (Integer cukes) -> {
            System.out.format("Cukes: %n\n", cukes);
        });

    Then("I have a some step definition", () -> {
             throw new Exception();
        }); 

    Given("testlambda", () -> {
         System.out.println("Inside Given");
    });

    When("^the search phrase \"([^\"]*)\" is entered$", (String phrase) -> {
        System.out.println("Inside When");
    });

    Then("^results for \"([^\"]*)\" are shown$", (String phrase) -> {
        System.out.println("Inside Then");
    });
    }
```

Can anyone help me understand what are the advantages of using lambda expression?
And why the lambda should write in the construction?

Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: The previous apis used Java annotations (`@Then`). Not sure if its the main reason, but this example looks way more like how cucumber step definitions are implemented in other languages

Comment: Imho this is a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to enable Java Functional Programming Style while writing your Cucumber tests. Read more on functional programming features [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-functional-programming/index.html). Key features would be:

- Pure Functions
- No State
- No Side Effects
- Immutable Variables

Comment: Possibly so -- it's clear what the benefits of functional programming are.... But specifically how does the lambda-style Cucumber step definition actually support functional programming any better than simply defining these as methods? I can't think of a reason other than perhaps it's a more "DSL-like" syntax that reduces the number of Java-language keywords like "public void" for each step?